# How to get row id of newly inserted row in jqgrid using inline insert

Tags: jquery, json, free-jqgrid

I am using free jqgrid version 4.13 and i am using inline insert for inserting new rows, is there a way to to get the id of the inserted row so i can use that id to get the row json object. Also can i call the save event on enter key so i don't have click the save button on the pager when ever i insert a new row.

```js
jQuery("#43rowed3").jqGrid({
    url:'server.php?q=2',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:55},
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, editable:true},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:100,editable:true},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",editable:true},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",editable:true},        
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",editable:true},     
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false,editable:true}     
    ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#p43rowed3',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    editurl: "server.php",
    caption: "Using navigator"
});

jQuery("#43rowed3").jqGrid('navGrid',"#p43rowed3",{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
jQuery("#43rowed3").jqGrid('inlineNav',"#p43rowed3");
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use `aftersavefunc` callback of inline editing or the event  `jqGridInlineAfterSaveRow`, which will be called after successful saving the row on the server. What exactly you want to do in the place? Do you need to set new rowid and the value in `id` column to the value generated in the database and returned by `editurl: "server.php"`?

Comment: By the way, you can remove `index` property from all items of `colModel`. You can remove `<div id="p43rowed3"></div>` from HTML, replace `pager: '#p43rowed3'` to `pager: true` and remove `"#p43rowed3"` from parameters of `navGrid` and `inlineNav` .